# Combine Solr results with external REST API results

Tags: rest, solr

I would like to combine Solr search results with the results from an external REST API. The combined results should be reordered. The criteria for reordering has not be established. There is an constraint that the external REST API results can **not** be stored due to the SLA. The entire process has to happen in memory and be fast because it will part of a web application.

What is the best approach?

Is there a way to hack Solr? Should it happen in the web application layer? Should another REST API be created that combines the results? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem sounds to be the REST API. If you have to go out and get results, you need to cache them, etc. So, if that's not an issue for you, the rest should not be as well.

Solr is *very* hackable. You can define custom [Search Components](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/RequestHandlers+and+SearchComponents+in+SolrConfig#RequestHandlersandSearchComponentsinSolrConfig-SearchComponents) stack, you can define [custom post-filters](http://qaware.blogspot.ca/2014/11/how-to-write-postfilter-for-solr-49.html). You could probably use some logic from the Elevation Component to protect your order or just implement your own order.